# Find a point on the Poincare plane

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Find a point $P$ on the line $_{-3}L_{\sqrt{7}}$ in the Poincare plane whose coordinate (ruler) is $2$.

Let $P =(x,y)$. The line is on the Poincare plane, so it is a semicircle on the upper half-plane with center $-3$ and radius $\sqrt{7}$. The ruler equation for a Poincare plane is $\ln(\frac{x-c+r}{y})$ which equals $2$. Thus $\ln(\frac{x-c+r}{y}) = 2$.

Is my reasoning correct? How can I find point $P$?

Comment: @B.S. I've removed the non-euclidean-geometry tag, as we already have both [tag:hyperbolic-geometry] and [tag:spherical-geometry]. It would be much more useful to create a tag/synonym for (elliptic-geometry) when it is necessary.

Comment: @WillieWong: That's absolutely Ok. Thanks for remarking me that. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\mathscr{H}$, we know that $$_c\mathcal{L}_r=\{(x,y)\in\mathscr{H}\mid(x-c)^2+y^2=r^2\}$$ Considering the position of $P(x_p,y_p)$ we get $$(x_p+3)^2+y_p^2=7~~~~~~~~~~~~~(I)$$ But $f(x_p,y_p)=2$ where $$f(x,y)=\ln\left(\frac{x-c+r}{y}\right)$$ so $\ln\left(\frac{x_p+3+\sqrt{7}}{y_p}\right)=2$ and so $$(x_p+3)^2=(e^2y_p-\sqrt{7})^2~~~~~~~~~~~~~(II)$$ Now solve (I) and (II) simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you kind sir! So to solve $(I),(II)$ I let $(x_p+3)^2=7-y_p^2$ so $7-y_p^2 = (e^2y_p-\sqrt{7})^2$ and using Wolfram alpha I got the root to be $y= 0, \frac{2\sqrt{7}e^2}{1+e^4}$. Is that correct so far?

Comment: @Alex: I didn't check the values but note that in $\mathscr{H}$ we should have $y>0$.

Comment: thanks for reminding me that. So the $y$ value must be then $\frac{2\sqrt{7}e^2}{1+e^4}$ and not $0$. Thank you very much sir!

Comment: @Alex: I am glad I could help you. Regards